# Why is it called a boxing ring when the shape is a square?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Can someone please provide some history towards the usage of 'boxing ring'?
As we know, the boxing ring is in fact a square.
Just wondering does the ring date back to traditional battles in Ancient Roman times and the sport of boxing simply utilized?

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxing_ring): "The name "ring" is a relic from when contests were fought in a roughly drawn circle on the ground.".  Voting to close because this is not a Q. about the English language: the terminology is likely the same/equivalent is other languages.

Comment: @TrevorD do you have evidence that the terminology is the same in other languages, given that the square stage is a relic of English boxing rules from the 19th century?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it relates to the origin of terminology that is not specific to the English Language. Also the answer is readily available in other on-line sources, e.g. Wikipedia (see my comment).

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin [French translation](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the/french-word-for-boxing_ring.html): ring de boxe. In any case, Q. could also be closed for lack of research because the answer is readily available in Wikipedia.

Comment: @TrevorD I can find no pre-20th century citation for "ring de boxe," whigh suggests it may be a loan word from English similar to *le weekend*. At the very least, one would need to do more research to answer whether English is the origin language or how the phrase came into English, which makes it a valid question. If OP could elaborate based on Wikipedia's account, that'd be even better.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin Leaving aside other countries (which I should not have mentioned), Op's original Q. (Can someone please provide *some* history towards the usage of 'boxing ring'?) is answered by the cited Wikipedia article - that shows lack of research by Op. If appropriate, Op could have cited Wiki & asked for more info. Op cited **no research at all**, which makes 'lack of research' a legitimate reason for closure. Wiki refers to name *ring* as a 'relic'; its use in London in 1753 as a literal ring; & "first square ring" in 1838, which together more than answer Q. as it currently stands!

Comment: The current answer cites the OED, which is not a commonly available resource; however, [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ring#etymonline_v_15081) is easily accessible, and for *ring* says "Meaning 'place for prize fight and wrestling bouts' (early 14c.) is from the space in a circle of bystanders in the midst of which such contests once were held", and also cites "Grose, 1785". I agree with @TrevorD re lack of research; the reference to foreign languages was a red herring. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**ring**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/166069#eid25411490)

> A space, originally defined by a **circle** of spectators, now within a
>   roped **square** on a raised platform, for a boxing match, wrestling
>   match, etc. Also more fully boxing ring (see boxing n.2)

as in:

> 1654   M. Stevenson Occasions Off-spring     'To a drunken Porter
>   reeling into the Ring to wrastle with a Taylor.'

Although boxing matches are now conducted in square-shaped areas, such spaces are still called ‘rings’.  The Pugilistic Society introduced the first square ring in the year 1838, which was basically a 7.3-meter (24 feet) square. This is another reason why the ring where two boxers fight is also sometines referred to as the ‘square circle’.

Comment: Thank you IBF. That was exactly what I wanted to know, and confirms my suspicions... That boxing adopted 'square rings' in the 1800s but these continued to be referred to as    rings instead of relabelling.

Comment: @CurlyWatts Most of the information given in this answer was also provided in the Wikipedia article that I referred you to 36 hours ago!

Comment: @TrevorD comments to not suffice for answers, nor are answers intended to be in comments.

Comment: My understanding is that it is also inappropriate to provide an answer to a Q that ought to be closed for lack of research - which is why I put my 'answer' in a comment, where Op could read info for himself. Additionally, my comment was addressed to Op - not to you - on the basis that he was thanking you for info that I had provided him with some 36h previously!

Comment: answers are not to be provided in comments, whether OP's question warrants closure or not.